# Ubuntu cloned from HDD to SSD doesn't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

In my laptop, I had a 1 TB HDD with Windows, and 200 GB assigned to Ubuntu. 
I recently installed a 250 GB SSD on the laptop and cloned the Ubuntu partition to this SSD. When trying to boot the Ubuntu SSD, the computer actually boots to Ubuntu on the HDD.  How do I get Windows to boot from the HDD, Ubuntu to boot from the SSD, and delete the original Ubuntu partition from the HDD?

Comment: So, did you clone only the 200gb Ubuntu partition? Ubuntu (and Windows, in dual boot) will need the GRUB, which writes the boot sector code to instruct the computer where are things stored and how to interact with that stuff. I don't remember to have been seen any successful attempt to do it as you wish. I will follow up your question in order to see if somebody has a solution.

Comment: Searching in the web, i saw that can be for the uuid, and got that both uuid are the same:
/dev/sda6: UUID="a81fe7c6-00e7-4ef0-bae2-c3f74314c197" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="ee6a30c1-ef48-4ff0-9634-5bc5b83da532"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="a81fe7c6-00e7-4ef0-bae2-c3f74314c197" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="650a7bda-01"

The ssd is the sdb1 partition

Comment: This is what is said when I try to boot on the ssd linux
http://i.imgur.com/ZyolTPQ.png

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. IF you mean that you've got a 1TB HDD that's partitioned into 800G for Windows, and 200G for Ubuntu, and you've cloned the 200G Ubuntu partition to a 256G SSD, then...

**Note**: the order in which you implement will directly affect the outcome

- yes, your UUID's will be the same, and both cannot be connected at the same time, if you expect Ubuntu to boot where you want it to
- you can change the UUID on either HDD or SSD, by using `gparted`, and you may have to edit the new UUID into /etc/fstab
- if you delete the Ubuntu partition on the HDD prematurely, you may not be able to boot at all, as the GRUB core is installed there
- you can use `sudo update-grub` to see if it finds bootable systems on both HDD and SSD
- you may have to `sudo grub-install` on to /dev/sdb1 to make it bootable
- lastly, you'll need to use `gparted` to resize the partition on the SSD

Comment: The problem is I cant start the ssd ubuntu. Which uuid should I use, a random?

Comment: You may have to do some of this whilst booted from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. The UUID is directly tied to entries in /etc/fstab. GRUB is probably present on both drives, but the GRUB boot loader is only present on the 1TB HDD. I would probably change the UUID on the SSD first, then `sudo grub-install`, then `sudo update-grub`. I don't expect that it'll cleanly boot until later when you edit /etc/fstab on the SSD. Let `gparted` pick its own UUID, and then later you can use `sudo blkid` to determine what that UUID is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if is the best move but I did this:

1. First changed the UUID of the cloned ubuntu
2. Using grub customizer, copied the script that start the original ubuntu and pasted it on the cloned ubuntu script changing the UUID

That finally worked.